# Select DataGrid Cell in Template Column When Contents are Clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, datagridcell

So, I'm building a MySQL based program. I have many columns of data ranging from integers to doubles to dates to strings and have just decided to create the entire table out of Template Columns to accommodate them with a bit of consistency on both the UI and programming perspectives. The key point of this system is that it needs to be automatically sending new info to the database when the user exits the cell. In order to accommodate this in the past (where I had other passive issues) I simply located the column and row that has been selected, passed the coordinate to the underlying datatable, and used that to create update strings and update them to the database (this is a bit of a simplification).

This leads me into my new problem. Previously I was using a Text Column, where now I am using a Template Column with a textbox (or masked textbox). The Text Column would take care of cell selection inherently when the cell is clicked, so as to get ahold of the selection coordinates, while the Template Column does not work up the Visual Tree quite as kindly and does not select the container cell unless the cell is tabbed or otherwise navigated to, but not when clicked into. I have tried to manually select the cell by working up the Visual Tree manually when the textbox is clicked, but to no avail. The odd part is that the process works until I click into a column (which is identical) that I had to scroll over to get to.
Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to approach this problem? Here is a sample of my XAML and Code-Behind.

XAML:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="datagrid_1" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="UIElement_OnMouseLeftButtonDown1">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <xctk:MaskedTextBox LostFocus="textbox1_LostFocus" BorderBrush="Transparent" AutoSelectBehavior="OnFocus" Text="{Binding Path = penetration, Mode = TwoWay, ValidatesOnExceptions = true, NotifyOnValidationError = false, UpdateSourceTrigger = PropertyChanged}" Mask="000 %"  PromptChar=" " HidePromptOnLeave="True"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Code-Behind:

```
private void UIElement_OnLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender.GetType().ToString() == "TextBox")
    {
        var dep = (DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource;

        dep = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(dep);

        if (dep == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (dep is DataGridCell)
        {
            datagrid_1.SelectedItems[0] = dep;
        }
    }
}

private void textbox1_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        int rowindex = datagrid_1.Items.IndexOf(datagrid_1.SelectedCells[0].Item);                
        int columnindex = datagrid_1.SelectedCells[0].Column.DisplayIndex;
        string groupnumber = datatable1.Rows[rowindex][1].ToString();
        string columnname = datatable1.Columns[columnindex].ColumnName.ToString();
        string newinfo = datatable1.Rows[rowindex][columnindex].ToString();
        instantupdatecall(groupnumber, columnname, newinfo);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

I tried to simplify everything down to make it fit a little easier, but I left the important parts in. If anyone has any suggestions as to how to make this work, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your `OnFocus` `(AutoSelectBehavior)` event isn't firing?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [Data Binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612(v=vs.110).aspx).

Basically, have a "Model" class that holds the actual data which is presented and linked to the cells on the screen. Inside the setter you can write to your DB.

Example:

XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Source=list}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>                
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Date" Binding="{Binding Date}"/>
   </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

C#:

```
public class SomeObject
{
    string id;
    DateTime date;
    public string ID
    {
        get { return id; }
        set {
            id = value;
            UpdateDB();
        }
    }
    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return date; }
        set {
            date = value;
            UpdateDB();
        }
    }
    private void UpdateDB() {
        // Make some SQL, and work with your DB.
        // You maybe want to send arguments to this method about what has to be updated.
    }
}
```

If you know how to use the WPF and its Data Binding, you rarely need triggers and the hacks you tried in your example.
It is quite tricky to get the binding right for a DataGrid for the first time, but once set up, it makes your life a lot easier.

You can use the `<DataTemplate>` inside the DataGridColumns, they don't have to be `DataGridTextColumn` like I showed, but that's a different issue. :)